# FusedLocationProviderClient is not working in android 12 or lower. How to solve this

Tags: android, kotlin, android-12, fusedlocationproviderclient

I am getting address and lat and long in android 13 and also working lower version

fusedLocationProviderClient?.lastLocation?.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
val location: Location? = task.result

```
                Log.d("SDsadsad ", "sdsdit " + location)

                if (location != null) {
                    val geocoder = Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault())
                    var addresses: List<Address>? = null
                    try {
                        addresses =
                            geocoder.getFromLocation(location.latitude, location.longitude, 1)

                        Log.d("SDsadsad ", "sdsd " + addresses.toString())

                        langitude = addresses!![0].latitude.toString()
                        longitude = addresses!![0].longitude.toString()
                        address = addresses!![0].getAddressLine(0).toString()
                        pin = addresses!![0].postalCode.toString()

                        val telephone = this.getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
                        phone =  telephone.line1Number.toString()

                        val dev_id = Settings.Secure.getString(contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)

                        device_id = dev_id.toString()
                        brand = Build.BRAND.toString()
                        model = Build.MODEL.toString()

                        val str_dateTime = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Date())

                        alldataShowWaterMark = "User Name: "+Constant.USER_FULL_NAME+"\n"+
                                "Langitude: "+langitude+"\n"+
                                "Longitude: "+longitude+"\n"+
                                "Address: "+address+"\n"+
                                "PinCode: "+pin+"\n"+
                                "Phone No.: "+phone+"\n"+
                                "Device Id: "+device_id+"\n"+
                                "Brand Name: "+brand+"\n"+
                                "Model No.: "+model+"\n"+
                                "Data On Time: "+str_dateTime+"\n"

                 

                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                        Log.d("SDsadsad ", "exception " + e.toString())
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hi!
Use android.location.LocationManager. It works great for all android versions.

Comment: please share the code or link.

Comment: Shared in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can get last known location from LocationActivity. It will be available from `LocationActivity.lastLocation`. Here I do not provide location permission handling, just extension function `permissionNotGranted` to check if app has necessary permissions.

```
import android.Manifest.permission
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.location.LocationListener
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.PersistableBundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat

class LocationActivity : Activity(), LocationListener {

    private var locationManager: LocationManager? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        initLocationManager()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        if (locationManager != null) locationManager?.removeUpdates(this)
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    private fun initLocationManager() {
        if (this.permissionNotGranted(permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ||
            this.permissionNotGranted(permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        ) return
        try {
            val minute = (60 * 1000).toLong()
            locationManager = getSystemService(LocationManager::class.java)
            if (locationManager?.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) == true)
                locationManager?.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    minute,
                    0f,
                    this
                )
            try {
                if (locationManager?.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) == true)
                    locationManager?.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        minute,
                        0f,
                        this
                    )
            } catch (exception: IllegalArgumentException) {
                Log.e("activate NETWORK_PROVIDER exception ", exception.localizedMessage)
            }
        } catch (exception: SecurityException) {
            Log.e("initLocationManager exception", exception.localizedMessage)
        }
    }

    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
        val bestLocation = getBestLocation(location) ?: return
        if (bestLocation != lastLocation) lastLocation = bestLocation
    }

    private fun getBestLocation(location: Location): Location? {
        if (lastLocation == null) return location
        val older =
            (if ((lastLocation?.time ?: 0L) < location.time) lastLocation else location)
                ?: return null
        val newer =
            (if (lastLocation == older) location else lastLocation) ?: return null
        if (older.accuracy <= newer.accuracy) return newer
        return if (newer.distanceTo(older) < newer.accuracy) older else newer
    }


    private fun Context.permissionNotGranted(permission: String) =
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

    companion object {
        var lastLocation: Location? = null
    }
}
```